# Disabling Lazy Loading does not work

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I did some research on disabling lazy loading in EF, and from what I could find, to disable lazy loading you either remove the `virtual` keyword, or set `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` to false in the `dbContext`

```
public string HolidayCode { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("HolidayCode")]
public HolidayProfile HolidayProfile { get; set; }

public DatabaseContext()
{
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the data returned is still null.

Comment: This code looks fine, can you add your query and your entities so we can understand what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe this helps: the opposite of lazy loading (lazy loading = false) is not eager loading, but NO loading. You have to do eager loading explicitly in code.